# Alternative to Windows Home Server on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, windows-home-server

I'm planning to setup a Windows Home Server at home.

However, since I'm also working as an ISV at home, I have a strong need for a Windows 2008 R2 Hyper-V server that hosts my virtual development/testing servers.
The problem is that I'm not so keen on having 2 servers running 24/7 at home ( a Home Server and a "Real" Server), so for me it would be ideal to have the same (well, at least the backup functionality with the client agents) functionality on the Windows 2008 R2 Server.

Are there any such solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not run the Home Server as a guest VM within Win2k8, and just beef up "real server" with more RAM/disk space? If all you're looking to do is eliminate one physical box, just use Hyper-V. Your ISV for your clients will be up and running for your backup functionality while your Home Server will be shut down until you need it and you can remotely turn it on.

Does my solution make sense or am I missing the question altogether?

Comment: Your answer do make sense. Since all (client)backup data can grow substantially on Home Server, can it use a dedicated hard disk when running as a Hyper-V guest? In other words, can I dedicate 2x1TB disks just for the Home Server guest?

Comment: Interesting indeed... http://www.edbott.com/weblog/?p=2061

Comment: I haven't done this myself (exactly). I don't use Hyper-V so I can't speak from experience, but I'm sure you can allocate specific storage volumes to WHS and have the other guest VMs use other volumes so that you can allow WHS capacity to grow. Currently, I use Citrix XenServer 5.5 and I run *everything* I can on it so I just have one beefy server doing everything for me. I turn on/off whatever VMs when I need them and for the majority of my needs a few guest VMs are all, the rest are off. Life is a lot easier with a virtualized solution so long as you have the resources to use as needed.

Comment: I suppose one can use the pass-through functionality in Hyper-V in order to make a disk solely available to the WHS VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

i've tried, homeserver hates VMs, though it IS possible with vmware.

My solutions are these:
**Homeserver** does media streaming - Install ORB on server 2008 r2.

**Homeserver** does file serving with drive extender - Just when you add a second drive to server2008, and in Disk Manager right click your existing 'file serving drive' and click EXTEND VOLUME (grey unless you have an empty drive available), wham bam infinitely dynamically spanned drives all keeping your same drive letter and folder shares without worry of any "disk full" error messages. Homeserver has that step automated, but we're better than that! Automation is a crutch!

**Homeserver** has plugins - they suck, and you're smarter than plugins, so...

----------If you want to have a utorrent service on your computer look [HERE](http://mswhs.com/2007/07/02/how-to-install-utorrent-on-windows-home-server/).

----------If you want to automate backups to your server, use Comodo, NASBackup or synctoy!

----------You can make a domain for all your home computers, or make the shares PUBLIC: (http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Windows_Server_2008_File_Sharing)

----------You GAIN the ability to have a 100% flexible server to do whatever you want, EMAIL, DNS, PROXY, ISA, VOIP, APPSERVING, GAME HOSTING, STREAMING AAC/MP3 RADIO TO ANY DEVICE ANYWHERE!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have a different experience than what you suggests though. My Windows Home Server VM guest has been running 24/7 for 5 months now without any glitch at all. And this is on Microsoft Server 2008 R2 with the Hyper-V role.